# Syntax in QGIS Rule properties

Tags: qgis

I struggle with QGIS and some drawings of water pipes for a water company. According to the program it is possible to place different signatures for different components (stopcocks, T-pieces, etc.)
From the various data located in the file "attribute table" I have to define that: the symbol is used if the value in column UNDERKLASS is equal to U22

Answer (score 2):

```
UNDERKLASS = 'U22'
```

There are multiple examples online, e.g.

[image]

Just google for QGIS rule-based renderer.